# Why is the asp.net mvc model binder producing system.string[]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a form that is posting what is effectively an object dictionary to my controller action. So we get an `IEnumerable<EditThemeAttributeModel>`

```
        public class EditThemeAttributeModel
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }
        }
```

When I look at the Request.Form collection I see what I would expect:

```
    [1] "Attributes[0].Name"    string
    [2] "Attributes[0].Value"   string
    [3] "Attributes[1].Name"    string
    [4] "Attributes[1].Value"   string
    [5] "Attributes[2].Name"    string
    [6] "Attributes[2].Value"   string
```

However, when I try an attempt to get the value of one of the `EditThemeAttributeModel` it isn't a simple type as I would expect, it's a string array:

```
-   Value   {string[1]} object {string[]}
                [0] "#ffffff"   string
```

I can work around this by using the Request.Forms collection directly, but just wanted to understand this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All posts from http requests are, by default, strings. Since you're referencing an object rather than a typed object it defaults to string because the data coming from the browser is a string. If you want it to not be a string I suggest you type your object or you can create your own model binder for `EditThemeAttributeModel`.

Comment: yes I know that, but that wasn't the question. The question is why does the model binder produce a string array `string[]` when we pass it a collection of objects.

Comment: Because by default you can include multiple values for the same name for a given post value. `id=1&id=2&id=3` since you're not specifically asking for a `string` but an `object` the model binder assumes it can be an array because it can't convert it directly to a type. The array creation is that last call of the model binder because it basically couldn't figure out what you really wanted. I'd gather it's doing this just to be safe.

Comment: You can follow the model binder code in the source and see why exactly it's doing what it's doing. I did this a while back to answer a similar question I had when creating an automatic model binder. http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68345#266460 look at `BindSimpleModel` (the actual conversion is in ValueProviderResult)